# fill array with random numbers

Tags: c#, sorting, for-loop, random, console-application

I have a little problem.
I want fill my array with 100 random numbers.
The problem is i have a lot of the same numbers 2/4 of my array is 0
then 1/4 89 andso how is this possible ???

thanks for helping

```
public void arrayreverse()
{
    int[] arr = new int[100];
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int rand = r.Next(0, 100);
        arr[i] = rand;
        Array.Sort(arr);
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You sort the array *inside* the loop. That's the bug.

Comment: I agree with @JamesKPolk. You are overwriting entries because of the sorting that you perform on each iteration.

Comment: While the sorting would cause performance issues it doesn't get to the fact that Random doesn't work well in tight loops.  It is mostly based on computer time so values create in tight loops have a high likely hood of having repeat values.

Comment: This is mathematically interesting for me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: If you want a "better" random in C# (or other .Net languages) use this ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are not getting as many duplicates as you think you are.  You are dumping the index after you sort and reverse your data. you will always print the lowest value in the array the way it is coded.

Comment: @MatthewWhited "Random doesn't work well in tight loops"??? I don't see any reason for that statement - the `Random` implementation is well defined piece of code and does not use any external inputs except possible initial seed to generate next number. I don't see how using loop vs. not using one would change that behavior.

Comment: Random is based on a time based seed.  Computers are so fast not they can end up using the same seed with and give you the same result between calls.  Don't trust me word go try it.

Comment: @MatthewWhited: That's not the problem. The random number generator is only seeded once.

Comment: The seed is used on every call.  Again try it.

Comment: I was simply starting why OP was seeing so many duplicate "random" values.  if you want a better random you could `Thread.Sleep(300)` on each loop or better still use the cryptographic random generator.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I suspect you are talking about different code when random *created* inside the loop (as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number), not the code OP provided (where `Random` created outside the loop, and presumably placed inside the function to provide [MCVE]).

Answer (score 3):

Since you sort and reverse the array inside the loop you basically force the biggest number to be last.

For example in 5 sized array:

```
i = 0
arr[i] = rand:
arr -> 5 0 0 0 0

sort and reverse
arr -> 5 0 0 0 0
output = 5

i = 1
arr[i] = rand:
arr -> 5 8 0 0 0

sort and reverse
arr -> 8 5 0 0 0
output = 5

i = 2
arr[i] = rand:
arr -> 8 5 7 0 0

sort and reverse
arr -> 8 7 5 0 0
output = 5

i = 3
arr[i] = rand:
arr -> 8 5 7 2 0

sort and reverse
arr -> 8 7 5 2 0
output = 2

i = 4
arr[i] = rand:
arr -> 8 7 5 2 0

sort and reverse
arr -> 8 7 5 2 0
output = 2
```

As you can see, your output will always be the smallest number and as you go on, less and less number generated by the `Random.Next` can be smaller than the current smallest so the current smallest will most likely appear again as the output.

If you want to make a list of 100 numbers and print them you can use this `Linq`:

```
(new int[100])
    .Select(x => r.Next(100))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

If you want the numbers to be distinct (all the numbers between 0 and 99 but you want them to appear only once) you can use the following code:

```
private static Random r = new Random();

public static int[] GetRandomArray(int size)
{
    SortedDictionary<double, int> sortedSet = new SortedDictionary<double, int>();
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {               
        sortedSet.Add(r.NextDouble(), index);
    }
    return sortedSet.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is easier to get right:

```
var randomNumbers = 
      Enumerable.Range(0, 100) // create sequence of 100 elements
      .Select(_ =>r.Next(0,100)) // for each element select random value
      .ToArray(); // convert to array.
```

As for your current sample - move sorting out of the `for` loop to fix bug.

Answer (score 2):

"Random" doesn't imply unique. You can still achieve the expected behavior by using a set:

```
    var takenNumbers = new SortedSet<int>();

    while (takenNumbers.Count != 100)
    {
        takenNumbers.Add(r.Next(0, 100));
    }

    var array = takenNumbers.ToArray();
```

It seams, however, that you want to build a unique *sequence* , not a set.

Here is code building a sequence:

```
    var takenNumbers = new HashSet<int>();

    var array = int[100];
    while (takenNumbers.Count != 100)
    {
        int rand = r.Next(0, 100);
        if (takenNumbers.Add(rand))
        {
           array[takenNumbers.Count - 1] = rand; 
        }
    }

    foreach(var number in arr)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Arrayreverse()
{
    int[] arr = new int[100];
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int rand = r.Next(0, 100);
        arr[i] = rand;
    }

    Array.Sort(arr);
    Array.Reverse(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: running that you get duplicates comment out the `Array.Sort(arr) && the Array.Reverse(arr)` you will see that you will get random numbers however there will be some duplicate numbers but not as many as there were with all the Sorting and Reverse code..

Comment: I thougt he want duplicates?

Comment: perhaps you need to read the question again the OP Clearly states the following 
`I want fill my array with 100 random numbers. The problem is i have a lot of the same numbers`

Comment: If you want random numbers, there are almost same numbers. But Feren said, that he has about 50% Zeros, what is strange.

Comment: remove the 2 lines from your code you posted run the code and you will see the difference.. your code is not going to yield the proper results..

Comment: @kame: It's not 50% zeroes.  The code always prints the lowest number found so far.

Comment: But Feren seems to want an sorted array in the end, right?

Comment: @recursive I think it is 50% zeros BECAUSE the code alway prints the lowest number found so far.

Comment: @kame: Yes, that's what I'm trying to say.  That means it's not strange to be 50% zeroes.  That's what one would expect.